# Relative Paths in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work with a multi-root workspace in VS Code. Here's my folder structure:

```
project-one
-node_modules
-public
--css
---styles.css
--img
---global
-----logo.svg
--js
---main.js
--index.html
project-two
project-three
```

When I reference files in my index.html file, VS Code always wants me to write it like this (in index.html):

```
src="img/global/logo.svg"
```

That doesn't really make sense to me. Logically, I would write the relative path to the logo with a leading `/` before `img` as the img folder is at the same level as index.html. However, that doesn't work.

Can anybody explain me why? And will the path declarations work correctly like this when I upload these files to the server (the content of the public folder will then be at the root)?

Thanks.

Comment: Only absolute paths start with a leading `/` which distinguishes them from relative paths. So, by definition, you would not put a leading `/` in a relative path.